# PCRE Regex MUST contain a symbol in middle of pattern

Tags: regex

Trying to match a pattern where a symbol MUST occur in the middle of the pattern.

https://regex101.com/r/Z8CIFD/1

```
("fi[\w\W]{15,55}me")
```

The regex should look for and capture  "file.name"  but the pattern MUST contain " or + in the middle of the match.  Example: should match the last two, but not the first.

```
"file.name"
"fi"+"le.na"+"me"
"f"+"il"+"e.n"+"a"+"me"
```

Worked on this a while and can't get it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a positive lookahead for the required characters.

Comment: Due to not knowing where the "+" could appear, I'm not sure how to implement the lookahead.  My attempts aren't matching/capturing the entire file.name pattern.  Could you provide an example please?

Comment: I posted an answer an hour ago.

Answer (score 0):

Use a positive lookahead that matches `.+[+"].`, which matches `+` or `"` somewhere in the middle of the text.

```regex
(?=.+[+"].)"f["+]*i["+]*l["+]*e["+]*\.["+]*n["+]*a["+]*m["+]?e"
```

The main pattern after the lookahead matches `"file.name"` with any number of `"` and `+` between each character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/MyEttt/1)